How to draw shaded cross arc region using tikz
I want to draw a shaded cross-arc region using Tikz. Can someone help?
I want to draw a shaded region as follows. It's not a rectangle,the sides are arcs.

The following is the maximum I could come up with
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.5);

\fill[pattern=north east lines] (30:1.5) arc[start angle=30, end angle=45, radius=1.5] -- (45:2) arc[start angle=45, end angle=30, radius=2] -- cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

And the output I got:

I want the shaded region to be right to center of the circle and with a border.

On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a minimal working example (MWE): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

welcome! can you post the code you've got so far? since you specify tikz, I assume you've started with tikz and have something already.

Add draw as option to your path to add a border. The right side is at 0deg. So your arc should go over the range -10:10 for example.

Like this?

With use of \arrows.meta, patterns.meta  and quotes library:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                patterns.meta,
                quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = Stealth,
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto=right, inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize, sloped}
                    ]
\draw[thick] (0,0) circle (1.5);
\draw[pattern={Lines[angle=45,distance={3pt}]},
      pattern color=blue]
      (-15:1.5) to ["$dr$"]  ++ (-15:0.5)  arc (-15:15:2) -- (15:1.5)   arc (15:-15:1.5) ;
\draw[->]   (1.5,0) -- (1,0);
\draw[->]   (2.0,0) -- (2.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

